# Code for colors in javascript at the final result

Tags: javascript

I write with translate ! I have a script js that calculates two numbers.

`number_one - number_two;` Everything works but I want the result to be colorful;

Can you help me do that?

```
 1. If the result is plus ( a-b = c )( 4-2 = 2 ) = color green; 
 2. If the number is negative ( a-b = -c ) ( 2-4 = -2 ) = red color;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById('number_one').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('number_two').value;
  var rezultat = parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
  document.getElementById('summa').innerHTML = rezultat;
}
```

```html
<div> <input type="text" id="number_one"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" id="number_two"> </div>
<div class="test">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <p id="summa"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: put the result in a span tag with css. you can use a if else statement to set a variable with a color and then give the span tag that color; Simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style.color` to set color to element as

```
  if(rezultat > 0){
   document.getElementById('summa').style.color = "green";
   }else{
   document.getElementById('summa').style.color = "red";
   }
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById('number_one').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('number_two').value;
  var rezultat = parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
  document.getElementById('summa').innerHTML = rezultat;
  if(rezultat > 0){
   document.getElementById('summa').style.color = "green";
   }else{
   document.getElementById('summa').style.color = "red";
   }
}
```

```html
<div> <input type="text" id="number_one"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" id="number_two"> </div>
<div class="test">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <p id="summa"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ))

Answer (score 0):

as you want to have red for negative and green for positive, I am updating my answer as below. Just change the last line as below

```
 var requiredElement=document.getElementById('summa').innerHTML;

requiredElement.innerHTML=rezultat;

requiredElement.style.color=rezultat>0?'green':'red';
```

Comment: I want red to appear if the result is negative
and if it is positive to appear green

Comment: Changed my answer ... please have a look